# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

So I have a spring project that I will want to use with a h2 database but am having some trouble with the initial set up and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. 
Here are my dependencies in my pom file.

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.196</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

and here is my beans.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd"
    xmlns:context="https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context"
    xmlns:jdbc="https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc">

<context:component-scan base-package="darragh"></context:component-scan>

<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="h2">
    <jdbc:script location="schema.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="data.sql" />
</jdbc:embedded-database>
```

I am getting the following errors.

> Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'context:component-scan' of schema namespace 'https://mvnrepository.com/
>    artifact/org.springframework/spring-context'

and

> Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for element 'jdbc:embedded-database' of schema namespace 'https://mvnrepository.com/
>    artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc'

Forgive me as I'm new to spring and don't understand why I am these error messages

Comment: try to have same version for `spring-context` and `spring-jdbc`

Comment: @Deadpool Ah ok updated the question with same versions. Still same error though

Comment: `http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd` add this in `xsi:schemaLocation` can you try this

Comment: @Deadpool When you say add do you mean replace what's already in the " ". By replacing it with your line I get the following error 
"Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
 - SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-
  context-3.0.xsd' must have even number of URI's."
on line 6 my jdbc one